# Choosing Statistical Test for my dataset

Tags: anova, spss, manova, mancova

I was wondering if someone could help me. I have a dataset from a clinical trial which tests the impact of therapy on a group of cannabis users with psychotic symptoms. It's a randomised control trial and 90 participants were assigned to 1 of 3 groups (long therapy/brief therapy/standard care) then their cannabis use and psychotic symptoms measured at baseline and then at follow up. I also have data on how long they've had a psychosis diagnosis and how long they've smoked cannabis.

The research questions I'd like to address are:
- Is there a significant difference between baseline and outcome result for each of the therapies and if so:
Is it affected by how long they've had a diagnosis and how long they've smoked cannabis

I'm thinking of doing a 3x2x2 mixed MANOVA but am unsure!

Answer (score 1):

Your therapy, $T$, is a fixed effect with three levels: long, brief, and standard. I'm assuming that cannabis use, $U$, is a continuous variable (ounces smoked per day / week), which is then a random effect. By these two, I believe your motion to use a mixed effect model is appropriate. Diagnosis length, $D_L$ is also a random effect. Your outcome is the change from baseline, $\Delta_{\text{symp}}$, which is continuous.

Therefore, your model should look like

$$
\Delta_{\text{symp}} = \beta_0 + \beta_1T_{\text{long}} + \beta_2T_{\text{brief}} + \beta_3U + \beta_4D_L + \epsilon,
$$

where $\epsilon$ is some random error (that we hope is normally distributed). Note that $T_{\text{long}}$ and $T_{\text{brief}}$ are indicator vectors for the treatment level, with $T_{\text{standard}}$ as the baseline (its effect is part of $\beta_0$ in our model). I would run this as a multiple regression model, and check the following:

1. Check that the errors (model residuals) are normally distributed (with mean of 0). I would plot a density estimate of them and check that it's reasonably symmetric and unimodal. You can also use a Q-Q plot for this. If not, you will probably have to [transform your data](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/318).
2. Check that the predictors are not highly correlated with each other. Build a correlation matrix of the predictors, and look to see if any correlations are greater than 0.8 in absolute value. If so, your model may have issues from [Multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity).

After you run this model, check the confidence intervals for each $\beta_i$ value. If the confidence interval for a particular $\beta_i$ value does not contain 0, then that predictor is significantly related to the outcome (*if you have confirmed that your predictors are not too strongly correlated with each other*).

[Here](http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial.pdf) is a good summary of how this all works. If you still have questions, feel free to email or message me.